# Recursively join a field to its parsed segments

Tags: sql, postgresql, parsing, recursion, join

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
___COL_1___
'|A|B|C|'
'|D|A|'
'|X|Y|Z|A|'
'|Y|X|'
...
```

And I want to create a new table that looks like this:

```
___COL_1___ ...........    ___COL_2___
'|A|B|C|'.....................'|A|'
'|A|B|C|'.....................'|B|'
'|A|B|C|'.....................'|C|'
'|D|A|'........................'|D|'
'|D|A|'........................'|A|'
'|X|Y|Z|A|B|C|'...........'|X|'
'|X|Y|Z|A|B|C|'...........'|Y|'
'|X|Y|Z|A|B|C|'...........'|Z|'
'|X|Y|Z|A|B|C|'...........'|A|'
'|X|Y|Z|A|B|C|'...........'|B|'
'|X|Y|Z|A|B|C|'...........'|C|'
...
```

So I want to recursively join the group to each item within the string.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need recursion, just:

- trim first and last `|` characters of the column,
- convert the result to an array,
- unnest the array,
- add `|` characters if you like them.

```sql
with my_data(col1) as (
values
    ('|A|B|C|'),
    ('|D|A|'),
    ('|X|Y|Z|A|'),
    ('|Y|X|')
)
select 
    col1, 
    format('|%s|', unnest(string_to_array(trim(col1, '|'), '|'))) as col2
from my_data

   col1    | col2 
-----------+------
 |A|B|C|   | |A|
 |A|B|C|   | |B|
 |A|B|C|   | |C|
 |D|A|     | |D|
 |D|A|     | |A|
 |X|Y|Z|A| | |X|
 |X|Y|Z|A| | |Y|
 |X|Y|Z|A| | |Z|
 |X|Y|Z|A| | |A|
 |Y|X|     | |Y|
 |Y|X|     | |X|
(11 rows)
```